# Is there a way to style individual array elements in js

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, styling

I am currently working on a memory game where I have a game board populated with divs created through `js`. I'm trying to add images to my array values.
Here is my array:

```
var memory_array = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H'];
```

I would like to attach an image to each pair to make my project more interesting. I am currently trying
`memory_array[0].style.background-image` and it is breaking my project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what way is it breaking your project?

Comment: Can you show more of your code?  Do you want to store an image name with each letter in the array?  Or are you asking how to display html elements using the js array as a data model?

Comment: you could style an element in the DOM tree, but you cannot style an item of a js array. Probably you have an error like _"style is not a property of memory_array"_

Answer (score 0):

It's `.backgroundImage`, but your array consists of char values, they don't have the property `style`. For calling `.style`, you have to get the `DOM` element, f.e. with `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByClassName`. I would recommend to give them class names (`.className`) and setting the images in css instead of using `.style.backgroundImage` directly.

Comment: could you give me an example of adding a className to the first element in my array?

Comment: why do you want to do that? like I said, you first have to create/get the `DOM` element, setting `.className` on your array element won't change the appearance.

Comment: My issue is that the array elements are not static. Upon page refresh they are randomized. I know how to style the static divs but I want to style the randomized elements. For example. On click the div will reveal one of my letter elements. Instead of revealing a letter I want to reveal an image of my choice.

Comment: Instead of assigning the elements to your `div`'s content, assign them to their class names. Then in your css you do something like `.card.A. { background-image: url_to_a_image }`

Answer (score -1):

The reason it is not working is because your array elements are strings and not objects. One easy solution would be to make your array like this:

```
var memory_array = [{name:'A'}, {name:'B'}, ...];
```

Now, after calling `memory_array[0].style-background-image:"SomeImage"`; Your first element would become:

```
{name: 'A',
 style-background-image: "SomeImage"
}
```

Note that this does **not** change any style directly. When building DOM elements you will have to call the property `style.backgroundImage` and apply it to each element

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would I proceed to style names on my style sheet or in my script file?

Comment: @Tone I would recomand you to use style sheet if you can and resort to js only when css cannot satisfy your need. Please post the part of js where you generate `divs` so we can have a better understanding on your problem.

Comment: `memory_array[0].style.background-image="SomeImage"` is invalid syntax.