# Assigning javascript array elements class or id for css styling

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I'm trying to assign class and id to items in an array I created in js and input into my html. I'm doing this so I can style them in my stylesheet. Each item will not be styled the same way.

I'm a beginner so trying to keep it to code I can understand and make it as clean as possible, i.e. not making each of these items an element in the html.

This part works fine:

```
var pool =['A','B','3','J','R','1','Q','F','5','T','0','K','N','C','R','U']
var letters = pool.join('');
document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = letters;
```

This part not so much:

```
var char1 = letters[1];
char1.classList.add('hoverRed');
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176870/is-there-a-way-to-style-individual-array-elements-in-js) that didn't work for me, it just showed `[object][object][object]` when I ran it.

Comment: Where's the HTML? You can't style JavaScript variables and that's what `char1` is. You need some HTML to apply the CSS to.

Comment: .classList is a property on an Element. In your example, char1 is set to "B". There is some code missing in your example I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code attempts to apply a style to an array element, but CSS only applies to HTML. If you wish to style one character in a string, that character must be wrapped in an HTML element (a `<span>` is the best choice for wrapping an inline value).

This code shows how to accomplish this:

```js
var pool =['A','B','3','J','R','1','Q','F','5','T','0','K','N','C','R','U']
var letters = pool.join('');

// Replace a specific character with the same character, but wrapped in a <span>
// so it can be styled
letters = letters.replace(letters[1], "<span>" + letters[1] + "</span>");

// Insert the letters string into the div
var theDiv = document.getElementById('key');

// Inject the string into the div
theDiv.innerHTML = letters; 

// Get a reference to the span:
var theSpan = theDiv.querySelector("span");

// Add the style to the <span> that wraps the character, not the character itself
theSpan.classList.add('hoverRed');
```

```css
.hoverRed {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="key"></div>
```

And, this snippet shows how you could apply CSS to any letter:

```js
var pool =['A','B','3','J','R','1','Q','F','5','T','0','K','N','C','R','U'];

// Leave the original array alone so that it can be manipulated any way needed
// in the future, but create a new array that wraps each array element within
// a <span>. This can be accomplished in several ways, but the map() array method
// is the most straight-forward.
var charSpanArray = pool.map(function(char){
  return "<span>" + char + "</span>";
});

// Decide which character(s) need CSS applied to them. This data can come from anywhere
// Here, we'll just say that the 2nd and 5th ones should.

// Loop through the new array and on the 2nd and 5th elements, apply the CSS class
charSpanArray.forEach(function(element, index, array){
  // Check for the particular array elements in question
  if(index === 1 || index === 4){
    // Update those strings to include the CSS
    array[index] = element.replace("<span>","<span class='hoverRed'>");
  }
});

// Now, turn the new array into a string
var letters = charSpanArray.join('');

// For diagnostics, print the string to the console just to see what we've got
console.log(letters);

// Get a reference to the div container
var theDiv = document.getElementById('key');

// Inject the string into the div
theDiv.innerHTML = letters;
```

```css
.hoverRed {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="key"></div>
```

Comment: Ok so, any array items created in javascript that I want to manipulate elsewhere have to have html tags around them. But if I want to manipulate all of them, or just set it up correctly from the start without having to replace, should my array look like this: var pool = [<span>A</span>,<span>B</span>,<span>3</span>,
 <span>J</span>,<span>R</span>,<span>1</span>,<span>Q</span>,<span>F</span>...]; ???    When I test run it it shows nothing...

Comment: @Homerade No, I don't think you are quite following me. You can manipulate the data in array elements all you like without HTML. But, if you want to display that data on a web page, that data must become part of the Document Object Model, which means that the data must be contained within HTML elements. Those HTML elements can then be styled with CSS. It is NOT a good idea for the array to contain HTML from the start because that imposes too much rigidity in the program (suppose you want to do something else with just the data - now you'd have to get rid of the HTML).

Comment: @Homerade The best approach is what I've done, which is to programmatically add the HTML. You'll notice in my answer that the `<span>` element is not added to the array itself, it's added to a temporary string that is then used as the contents of a `div` element.

Comment: @Homerade See my updated answer for an example of how you could manipulate the CSS of any letter.

Comment: Yes! I did some research on map(), I get it and I'm with you every step of the way (and it's working for me!). Two questions: 1) Why do you have to include the parameters "element, index, array" in the function? 2) As a follow up, is there any way to streamline adding a class to chunks of the array e.g. 'hoverRed' to pool[1-8] and 'hoverGrey' to the rest?

Comment: @Homerade When you use `map` (and other array methods, like `forEach`), the function you provide to `map` will automatically be passed 3 arguments that reference (in this order): the element being iterated over, the index position of the element in the original array and the array itself. In this case, I only needed to access the character being iterated, so I only set up an argument for `char`, which is the first argument passed to the function. I ignored the other two because I didn't need them to solve the problem, but they were still passed.

Comment: @Homerade But, in the `forEach`, I needed the "element" and the "index", so I set up those parameters. I wound up not needing the array reference, but didn't take it out because it doesn't hurt anything by being there. Remember, the argument is going to be passed whether you capture it with a parameter or not.

Comment: @Homerade *"is there any way to streamline adding a class to chunks of the array e.g. 'hoverRed' to pool[1-8] and 'hoverGrey' to the rest?"* I'm sure there are many ways to do it, but I think this is pretty streamlined, dynamic and scalable as it is.

Comment: for example: charSpanArray.forEach(function(element, index, array){  if(index === 1 [through] 8) { array[index] = element.replace("<span>","<span class='hoverRed'>")} else { array[index] = element.replace("<span>","<span class='hoverGrey'>"};

Comment: Oh, I see what you are after. Yes, sure that will work.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Marcus, you've really helped me understand this. I voted you up but it doesn't show bc this is my first interaction on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but missed one key thing.

In your example, pool contains characters.  When you combine them using join, you get a string.  Setting that string as the innerHTML of an element doesn't give the string super powers, it's still just a string.

In order to get a classList, you need to change your letters into elements and work with them.

I've included an es6 example (and a working plunker) of how to get the functionality you want below.

```
let pool = ['A','B','3','J','R','1','Q','F','5','T','0','K','N','C','R','U']

const letterToElement = function(char) {
  //Create the element
  let e = document.createElement("SPAN");

  //Create the text node
  let t = document.createTextNode(char);

  //Put the text node on the element
  e.appendChild(t);

  //Add the class name you want
  e.className += "hoverRed";
  return e;
};

//create your elements from your pool and append them to the "key" element
window.onload = function() {
  let container = document.getElementById("key");
  pool.map(l => letterToElement(l))
      .forEach(e => container.appendChild(e));  
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/mBhA60aUCEGSs0t0MDGu